# Connecting PC via Bluetooth SNP

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a widcomm example BluChat "WIDCOMM SDK RFComm Service" running on my PC with an USB dongle (BT-2400P). I would like to connect this chat from my HTC Desire. So I stared with the Java example http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html. This is also using BT RFComm. If I'm using my HTC as a server it work's fine, but I would like to use my PC as a server. Then .connect() comes back with "Service Discovery Failure".

I have modified the UUID string in the Java example to match the PC-application

```
       mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("5fc2a42e-144e-4bb5-b43f-4e61711d1c32"));
        mmSocket.connect();
```

What is missing?

Any help appreciated.

Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it should be SDP in the title.

Anyway, could it be this bug? http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/348c269f2ef88327/ecdf3268e9c58507

Answer (score 0):

Just like to inform other users reading this thread: this issue seems to be related to android 2.1. It works fine with 2.2 after upgrade.

BR Nicholas